# Using function pointers with singleton objects c++

Tags: c++, singleton, function-pointers

I am c++ novice and tried my luck googling and searching to find an answer for this, but to no avail. Most probably this should be some stupid question.

I always have trouble understanding function pointers and its syntax.

This is the first time I am using it in some *serious* code.

I have a **singleton** class like this. Singleton method is not shown.

```
class Derived:public base
{
    int fn();
    // This function has a single argument which 
    // is function pointer to any of the base class
    // function having same argument/return type of 
    // the singleton object.
};

class base
{
   public:
   int ConvertIntIndex(const unsigned int Index);
   int ConvertStringIndex(const unsigned int Index);
   int ConvertOidIndex(const unsigned int Index);
}
```

How to declare `fn()` and how to call this via singleton object. I tried different options and was unable to even compile this. I got so many errors and will post those details if required. I am having a tough time. Can anybody help or point out a duplicate if there exists? I will delete this post if there is one.

Thanks.

Comment: The first step to solving problems with Singletons is to get rid of the Singletons.

Comment: Instead of using old-style function pointers, look at [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: @DeadMG: I wish I could... :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Thanks. This is new for me. I will definitely check this. The code is for an embedded target and I am not sure about c++11 support, in case it is required. :(

Comment: What is the signature of the functions you want the pointer to point to? Is it `base (base*)`? Are they static or non-static member functions?

Comment: @Angew : Edited question. Thanks for the suggestion. Those are non static functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
class Derived: public base
{
    int fn(int (base::*arg)(unsigned int));
};
```

Inside `fn`, you would use `arg` like this:

```
return (this->*arg)(7);
```

The syntax `int (base::*p)(unsigned int)` creates a *pointer to member function.* You use it with a pointer (or reference) to an object to call the member function. To dereference the pointer, you use use `->*` with a pointer to object, or `.*` with an object itself.

Comment: This will definitely save my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can send pointer of base class as an argument to `fn()`. Why don't you post the error message as well?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean pointer to member function? Then try:(corrected on comments).and you need a base object to call fp

```
typedef double (base::*bfptr)(double);

int fn(bfptr fp);
```

Comment: -1: This won't even work. This would expand to `double (base::*)(double) fp`, which is incorrect syntax. You probably meant `typedef` instead of `#define`.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing syntax errors out of your answer.